# MATLAB, how to solve Index exceeds the number of array elements (1)?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

Why I can't plot the following code? The error is:

> Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).

What I'm trying to achive is that a user enters a scalar value `f` (such as 1500) anf `Ht` and `Hr`. So, I want to find value of `ahr` and `L` accondingliy and then plot `L` vs `f`. SO on `f` axis I shoud have 100,150,200,250,300,....,1500 and corrsponding values on `L` axis.

```
for i = 100:50:f
        cm = 0;
        ahr(i) = (1.1*log10(f(i))-0.7)*Hr-1.56*log10(f(i))-0.8;
        L(i) = 46.3+33.9*log10(f(i))-13.82*log10(Ht)-ahr+(44.9-6.55*log10(Hr))*log10(d)+cm;
        plot(f,L)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using Vectorized Approach to Evaluate Plots

Assuming `d`, `Ht` and `Hr` are scalars the following code should work. This script uses a vectorized approach where `f` is a vector that is used to evaluate the equations `ahr` and `L`. The equations `ahr` and `L` will now be evaluated for every element in `f` resulting in the  `ahr` and `L` being the same length as `f`. This method eliminates the need for a for-loop and works with MATLAB's strengths/capabilities.

[image: Command Window: User Inputs]

[image: Plot L vs f Vectorized Approach]

```
%Asking user for input values%
fmax = input("Please type in the maximum f: ");
Ht = input("Please type in the value of Ht: ");
Hr = input("Please type in the value of Hr: ");
cm = 0;
d = 1;

%Creating the vector of points to plot on%
f = (100:50:fmax);

ahr = (1.1*log10(f)-0.7)*Hr-1.56*log10(f) - 0.8;
L = 46.3 + 33.9*log10(f)-13.82*log10(Ht)-ahr+(44.9-6.55*log10(Hr))*log10(d);

clf;
plot(f,L,'Marker','.');
title("Plot L vs f");
xlabel("f"); ylabel("L");
xticks(f);
grid;
```

**Ran using MATLAB 2019b**