# MATLAB: Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 0

Tags: matlab, raster, geography

I downloaded code from https://github.com/qmzheng09work/VIIRS_timeseries
This code is used to process NPP/VIIRS nighttime light image series.
When I run the Time series modelling Code (TS_fitting_v1_batch.m) in MATLAB, it said Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 0.
I wish someone can help me to solve this problem, thanks a lot. lol

Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.

> In regress (line 84)
> In logistic_fitting_v1 (line 33)
> In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general (line 837)
> In parallel.internal.parfor.cppRemoteParallelFunction (line 53)
> Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.
> In regress (line 84)
> In logistic_fitting_v1 (line 33)
> In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general (line 837)
> In parallel.internal.parfor.cppRemoteParallelFunction (line 53)
> Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.Warning: X is rank deficient to within machine precision.Error using logistic_fitting_v1
> Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 0.

Error in TS_fitting_v1_batch (line 75)
parfor i=1:num_record

> > 

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% fitting VIIRS time series 
% Input: 
% <path> of the folding containing all the avg_rad and cf_cvg .csv files

% Output:
% export fitted model parameters and model performance variables to folder <out_path>

% output parameters:

% When:
% k=2 nlinfit algorihtm procudes the best estimation
% k=3 lsqcurvefit algorithm procudes the best estimation
% The time series is fitted by Logistic-Harmonic model (LogH):
% fun_full=inline('c(1)+c(2)./(1+exp(-c(3).*t+c(4)))+c(5).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(6).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(7).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(8).*cos(4*t*pi./12)','c','t');
% c(1)-c(8):c_est1,c_est2,c_est3,c_est4,c_est5,c_est6,c_est7,c_est8 
% RMSE,Rsquare


% When£º
% k=0 no change
% k=1 false change;
% k=4 LinH has a better fitting performance than LogH
% The time series is fitted by Linear-Harmonic model (LinH):
% fun_full_linear=inline('c(1)+c(2).*t+c(3).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(4).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(5).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(6).*cos(4*t*pi./12)','c','t');
% c(1)-c(6):c_est1,c_est2,c_est3,c_est4,c_est5,c_est6
% c_est7,c_est8=0;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% 
clear;
close all;
clc;

path='D:\Quanzhou_NTL\In\';
out_path='D:\Quanzhou_NTL\Out\';
files = dir([path,'*.','csv']);
num_file=length(files)/2;


 for j=1:num_file
    
    path_rad=[path,files(j*2-1).name];
    path_cvg=[path,files(j*2).name];
    
    rad=csvread(path_rad,1,1);
    cvg=csvread(path_cvg,1,1);
    
    if sum(rad(end,:))==0
        rad(end,:)=[];
    end
    
    if sum(cvg(end,:))==0
        cvg(end,:)=[];
    end
    
    num_obs=size(rad,2);
    num_record=size(rad,1);
    t=1:num_obs;
    
    k=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est1=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est2=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est3=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est4=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est5=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est6=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est7=zeros(num_record,1);
    c_est8=zeros(num_record,1);
    RMSE=zeros(num_record,1);
    Rsquare=zeros(num_record,1);

    
    parfor i=1:num_record
        fprintf('start i===%d\n',i);
        fprintf('i===%d\n',i);
        fprintf('end i===%d\n',i);
        [k_temp,c_est_temp,RMSE_temp,Rsquare_temp]=logistic_fitting_v1(t,rad,cvg,i);
        k(i,1)=k_temp;
        if length(c_est_temp)==6
            c_est1(i,1)=c_est_temp(1);
            c_est2(i,1)=c_est_temp(2);
            c_est3(i,1)=c_est_temp(3);
            c_est4(i,1)=c_est_temp(4);
            c_est5(i,1)=c_est_temp(5);
            c_est6(i,1)=c_est_temp(6);
            
        else
            c_est1(i,1)=c_est_temp(1);
            c_est2(i,1)=c_est_temp(2);
            c_est3(i,1)=c_est_temp(3);
            c_est4(i,1)=c_est_temp(4);
            c_est5(i,1)=c_est_temp(5);
            c_est6(i,1)=c_est_temp(6);
            c_est7(i,1)=c_est_temp(7);
            c_est8(i,1)=c_est_temp(8);
        end
        RMSE(i,1)=RMSE_temp;
        Rsquare(i,1)=Rsquare_temp;
        
        fprintf('i=%d\n',i);
    end
    
    paras=[c_est1,c_est2,c_est3,c_est4,c_est5,c_est6,c_est7,c_est8,RMSE,Rsquare,k];
    outName=files(j*2-1).name;
    outFile=[out_path,outName(1:(strfind(files(j*2-1).name,'Viirs')-1)),'_paras.csv'];
    csvwrite(outFile,paras);
 end
```

```
function [k,c_est,RMSE,Rsquare]=logistic_fitting_v1(t,rad,cvg,idx)

%%%%
% k=0; no change；
% k=1 false change;
% k=2 nlinfit wins;
% k=3 lsqcurvefit wins;
% k=4 linear better than log

%%%%%
RMSE=0;
Rsquare=0;
y_rad=rad(idx,:);
y_cvg=cvg(idx,:);
num_obs=length(t);

%%
y_rad0=y_rad; % y_rad0: raw time series; y_rad: cf_cvg masked time series
t0=t;
mask_idx=find(y_cvg<=quantile(y_cvg,.1));
t(mask_idx)=[];
y_rad(mask_idx)=[];

%%  model and estimate change or not
fun_log=inline('c(1)+c(2)./(1+exp(-c(3).*t+c(4)))','c','t');
fun_season=inline('c(1).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(2).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(3).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(4).*cos(4*t*pi./12)','c','t');
fun_full=inline('c(1)+c(2)./(1+exp(-c(3).*t+c(4)))+c(5).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(6).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(7).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(8).*cos(4*t*pi./12)','c','t');
fun_full_linear=inline('c(1)+c(2).*t+c(3).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(4).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(5).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(6).*cos(4*t*pi./12)','c','t');

fun_full2=@(c,t)c(1)+c(2)./(1+exp(-c(3).*t+c(4)))+c(5).*sin(2*t*pi./12)+c(6).*cos(2*t*pi./12)+c(7).*sin(4*t*pi./12)+c(8).*cos(4*t*pi./12);

X=[ones(1,length(t));t]; % y=b+ax
[B,BINT,R,RINT,STATS]=regress(y_rad',X');

P_Value=STATS(3);
threshold=3; % threshold of false change;

if P_Value>0.05 % && abs(B(2))<=0.05  %说明这里需要给一个 change mag的 threshold？？ 但是这个会不是预先就盖棺定论了 影响了后面对变化类型的分类？？？
    fprintf('P_Value=%.2f, slope=%.4f\n',P_Value,abs(B(2)));
    
    fprintf('\n**********************Result**********************\n\n');
    fprintf('No change. No significant change is detected!\n\n');
    fprintf('**********************Result**********************\n\n');
    k=0;
    c_est=B;
    X=[ones(1,length(t));t;sin(2*t*pi./12);cos(2*t*pi./12);sin(4*t*pi./12);cos(4*t*pi./12)]; % y=b+ax
    [B,BINT,R,RINT,STATS]=regress(y_rad',X');
    RMSE=sqrt(sum((y_rad-fun_full_linear(B,t)).^2)/length(t));
    c_est=B;
    Rsquare=STATS(1);
else
    
    %%
    % estimating initial parameter
    c1_0=mean(y_rad(1:10));
    c2_0=mean(y_rad(end-9:end))-mean(y_rad(1:10));
    Smag=0.5*(std(y_rad(1:10))+std(y_rad(end-9:end)));
    y_temp=c2_0./(y_rad-c1_0-Smag)-1;
    mask_idx2=find(y_temp<=0);
    y_temp(mask_idx2)=[];
    t_temp=t;
    t_temp(mask_idx2)=[];
    y_est=log(y_temp);
    X=[ones(1,length(t_temp));t_temp];
    [B0,BINT,R,RINT,STATS0]=regress(y_est',X');
    c0=[c1_0,c2_0,-1*B0(2),B0(1),1,1,1,1];
    
    %% nlinfit
    
    opts = statset('nlinfit');
    opts2=opts;
    opts2.MaxIter=2000;
    opts.MaxIter=1000;
    opts.Robust='on';
    
    c_est1=nlinfit(t,y_rad,fun_full,c0,opts);
    %%%这边只考虑 mask掉 outlier之后的 (t,y_rad)用来评价拟合优度
    Rsquare1=calculate_R(fun_full,c_est1,t,y_rad);
    RMSE1=sqrt(sum((y_rad-fun_full(c_est1,t)).^2)/length(t));
    fprintf('nlinfit\t');
    fprintf('RMSE=%.3f,  R-Square=%.3f\n',RMSE1,Rsquare1);
    disp(c_est1)
    
    %% ls
    options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt','MaxIterations',2000);
    lb = [];
    ub = [];
    [c_est2,norm,res,ef,out,lam,jac] = lsqcurvefit(fun_full2,c0,t,y_rad,lb,ub,options);  %% ef >0 =收敛 otherwise 不收敛
    Rsquare2=calculate_R(fun_full,c_est2,t,y_rad);
    RMSE2=sqrt(sum((y_rad-fun_full(c_est2,t)).^2)/length(t));
    if ef<0
        fprintf('不收敛');
    else
    end
    fprintf('lsqcurvefit\t');
    fprintf('RMSE=%.3f,  R-Square=%.3f,  ',RMSE2,Rsquare2);
    fprintf('LM iterations=%d\n',out.iterations);
    disp(c_est2)
    
    %% linear regression
    X=[ones(1,length(t));t;sin(2*t*pi./12);cos(2*t*pi./12);sin(4*t*pi./12);cos(4*t*pi./12)]; % y=b+ax
    [B,BINT,R,RINT,STATS]=regress(y_rad',X');
    RMSE3=sqrt(sum((y_rad-fun_full_linear(B,t)).^2)/length(t));
    
    
    fprintf('\n**********************Result**********************\n\n');
    
    if RMSE1<RMSE2  %% nlin is better；
        y_log_est=fun_log(c_est1(1:4),t0);
        mag_change=abs(mean(y_log_est(1:10))-mean(y_log_est(end-9:end)));
        if Rsquare1<0.3
            fprintf('Low R-square warning! R2=%.3f\n',Rsquare1);
        end
        if Rsquare1<STATS(1)
            k=4;
            c_est=B;
            Rsquare=STATS(1);
            RMSE=RMSE3;
            fprintf('Linear model wins\n\n');
            
        else
            if mag_change<=threshold
                fprintf('No change. False change is detected!\n\n');
                k=1;
                c_est=B;
                Rsquare=STATS(1);
                RMSE=RMSE3;
            else
                fprintf('nlinfit wins, and the estimated parameters are:\n');
                disp(c_est1)
                k=2;
                c_est=c_est1;
                RMSE=RMSE1;
                Rsquare=Rsquare1;
            end
            
        end
    else  %%% LM wins
        y_log_est=fun_log(c_est2(1:4),t0);
        mag_change=abs(mean(y_log_est(1:10))-mean(y_log_est(end-9:end)));
        if Rsquare2<0.3
            fprintf('Low R-square warning! R2=%.3f\n',Rsquare1);
        end
        if Rsquare2<STATS(1)
            k=4;
            c_est=B;
            Rsquare=STATS(1);
             RMSE=RMSE3;
            fprintf('Linear model wins\n\n');
        else
            if mag_change<=threshold
                fprintf('No change. False change is detected!\n\n');
                k=1;
                c_est=B;
                Rsquare=STATS(1);
                RMSE=RMSE3;
            else
                fprintf('lsqcurvefit wins, and the estimated parameters are:\n');
                disp(c_est2)
                k=3;
                c_est=c_est2;
                RMSE=RMSE2;
                Rsquare=Rsquare2;
            end
            
        end
    end
    fprintf('**********************Result**********************\n\n');
end
```

```
function R_square=calculate_R(fun,para,x,y)
R_square=0;
y_est=fun(para,x);
SST=sum((y-mean(y)).^2);
SSE=sum((y-y_est).^2);
R_square=1-SSE/SST;
```

Tried nothing, in fact I am not familiar with MATLAB.
My MATLAB version: R2023a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MATLAB, how to solve Index exceeds the number of array elements (1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440516/matlab-how-to-solve-index-exceeds-the-number-of-array-elements-1)

Comment: When posting an error message, please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. Otherwise it's impossible to know what went wrong or where. ---- Just dumping code here and hoping someone will fix it is naive, you need to do the work, we just answer questions about programming. You should start by reading [mre] and [ask].

Comment: Type the following at the command line before running your program: dbstop if error. Then run your code. It will pause at the error with all variables intact. Examine them to determine why an index or variable size is not as expected. Then backtrack in your code to figure out why.